# Fedora hangs at black screen before booting with systemd

Tags: fedora, boot, graphics

I have recently installed Fedora on my PC from a live USB.
It was necessary to use Basic Graphics Mode for the installation, as systemd would hang at the message `starting: terminate plymouth boot screen`.

I have now been able to boot into Fedora using Basic Graphics Mode and update the kernel and the graphics driver `amdgpu` with `dnf upgrade`.

But if I now try to boot without Basic Graphics Mode, it just results in black screen and a unresponsive PC.
I don't think systemd is started, as I don't reach the classic rolling text screen but just the black screen.

What could cause this problem?
And how do I proceed with figuring out what the problem is?

Comment: can you switch to another tty ( ctrl+alt+f2/f3/etc) from the "black screen" to where you have access to your terminal? Also are you using Grub to boot with or the Live Installation?

Comment: No, there is no access to another tty.
Yes I am now using GRUB to boot the installed OS.
Its from GRUB I am able to edit the, boot variables (?), to include `nomodeset` and access the OS in Basic Graphics Mode.

Comment: See if you can boot the system to terminal:
boot to grub -> 'e' key -> boot parameters screen.
In this screen arrow down to the line starting with "linux" and across to "quiet splash" .
replace quiet splash and ALL after with " systemd.unit=multi-user.target " with out the quotes.
Key combo clt+x to continue the boot process to TTY1.

Comment: Yes, that works.
I now have access to a working terminal.

Comment: Log in here on this terminal with your username and password.

Now let's see what the system does when we start the GUI: `systemctl isolate graphical.target`

Comment: Some text flashes over screen, too fast for me to read. (Though i saw some red text).
A splash screen appears for a second or two and now it's stuck on a unresponsive black screen with white underscore in the top left corner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103443/discussion-between-sorenhn-and-donald-l-wilson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has resolver itself by waiting for a newer version of the kernel and installing it.

I didn't figure out what the root course of the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to login and then this occurred or did this occur after logging in and running the
`systemctl isolate graphical.target` command?

It might best to run a file system check/repair from a live environment ( liveDVD). If you can and still have your
 liveDVD on hand easy and quick enough to do, to rule out a file system problem.

Comment: Yes, I was able to login and run the command, which resulted in the flashing text, and now black screen as described in the comment.

Comment: Okay this is weird.
I have rebooted the PC and tried to boot to the terminal again.
But it before the login at a line saying `[  2.362264] [drm] ib test in ring 12 succeeded`?

Comment: that I  believe is referring to an issue with the linux-firmware package and your amdgpu [reddit] (https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/5vgfus/be_aware_that_updating_to_the_newest/)

Comment: Oh never mind about the ring 12 stuff, I just didn't edit the boot options (?) correctly.
But I still end up whit a black screen when running `systemctl isolate graphical.target`?